# Remove duplicates from list of lists by column value

Tags: python

I have a list of list that look like this, they have been sorted so that duplicate IDs are arranged with the one I want to keep at the top..

```
[
    {'id': '23', 'type': 'car', 'price': '445'},
    {'id': '23', 'type': 'car', 'price': '78'},
    {'id': '23', 'type': 'car', 'price': '34'},
    {'id': '125', 'type': 'truck', 'price': '998'},
    {'id': '125', 'type': 'truck', 'price': '722'},
    {'id': '125', 'type': 'truck', 'price': '100'},
    {'id': '87', 'type': 'bike', 'price': '50'},
]
```

What is the simplest way to remove rows that have duplicate IDs but always keep the first one? In this instance the end result would look like this...

```
[
    {'id': '23', 'type': 'car', 'price': '445'},
    {'id': '125', 'type': 'truck', 'price': '998'},
    {'id': '87', 'type': 'bike', 'price': '50'},
]
```

I know I can remove duplicates from lists by converting to set like `set(my_list)` but in this instance it is duplicates by ID that I want to remove by

Comment: There is a list of dictionaries not a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably convert to Pandas DataFrame and then use drop_duplicates

```
import pandas as pd
data = [
{'id': '23', 'type': 'car', 'price': '445'},
{'id': '23', 'type': 'car', 'price': '78'},
{'id': '23', 'type': 'car', 'price': '34'},
{'id': '125', 'type': 'truck', 'price': '998'},
{'id': '125', 'type': 'truck', 'price': '722'},
{'id': '125', 'type': 'truck', 'price': '100'},
{'id': '87', 'type': 'bike', 'price': '50'},
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id'], inplace=True)
print(df.to_dict('records'))

# Output
# [{'id': '23', 'type': 'car', 'price': '445'}, 
# {'id': '125', 'type': 'truck', 'price': '998'}, 
# {'id': '87', 'type': 'bike', 'price': '50'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already hav the list sorted properly, a simple way to do this is to use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to grab the first element of each group in a list comprehension:

```
from itertools import groupby

l= [
    {'id': '23', 'type': 'car', 'price': '445'},
    {'id': '23', 'type': 'car', 'price': '78'},
    {'id': '23', 'type': 'car', 'price': '34'},
    {'id': '125', 'type': 'truck', 'price': '998'},
    {'id': '125', 'type': 'truck', 'price': '722'},
    {'id': '125', 'type': 'truck', 'price': '100'},
    {'id': '87', 'type': 'bike', 'price': '50'},
]

[next(g) for k, g in groupby(l, key=lambda d: d['id'])]

# [{'id': '23', 'type': 'car', 'price': '445'},
#  {'id': '125', 'type': 'truck', 'price': '998'},
#  {'id': '87', 'type': 'bike', 'price': '50'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer that involves no external modules or unnecessary manipulation of the data:

```
data = [
    {'id': '23', 'type': 'car', 'price': '445'},
    {'id': '23', 'type': 'car', 'price': '78'},
    {'id': '23', 'type': 'car', 'price': '34'},
    {'id': '125', 'type': 'truck', 'price': '998'},
    {'id': '125', 'type': 'truck', 'price': '722'},
    {'id': '125', 'type': 'truck', 'price': '100'},
    {'id': '87', 'type': 'bike', 'price': '50'},
]
seen = set()
result = [row for row in data if row['id'] not in seen and not seen.add(row['id'])]
print(result)
```

Result:

```
[{'id': '23', 'type': 'car', 'price': '445'},
 {'id': '125', 'type': 'truck', 'price': '998'},
 {'id': '87', 'type': 'bike', 'price': '50'}]
```

Note that the `not seen.add(row['id'])]` part of the list comprehension will always be `True`.  It's just a way of noting that a unique entry has been seen by adding it to the `seen` set.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take the name of the given list as `data`.

```
unique_ids = []
result = []
for item in data:
    if item["id"] not in unique_ids:
        result.append(item)
        unique_ids.append(item["id"])
print(result)
```

The result will be,

```
[{'id': '23', 'type': 'car', 'price': '445'},
 {'id': '125', 'type': 'truck', 'price': '998'},
 {'id': '87', 'type': 'bike', 'price': '50'}]
```

Comment: You're better off using a `set()` for `unique_ids`. When you use a `list`, the code has to traverse through the list every time you do a lookup on it.  For this trivial example, that doesn't really hurt you.  But for a real world example where the list being filtered contained many thousands of values, the difference could be at least measurable.  With that change made to your code, your answer is just an expanded out version of mine, which has value to show.  To use big O notation, without the set, your alg is O(N) complexity.  Using a set, it's O(1).

Comment: @CryptoFool I got understand. Thanks for explaining.